# Issue with simple calculation script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a really simple calculator for my website.

Basically, I want people to be able to put in their weight into a text box, click "Calculate Dose" and then the script multiplies their weight by a number that I will set myself for each page.

Here is what I have right now. Not only does it not work, but it also stops one of my ads from displaying:

```
<div>
<input id="inputweight" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onClick="calculate()">
<input id="result" />
</div>

<script>

    function calculate() {
    var weight = document.getElementById('inputweight').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var dosage = weight.value * 1;
    result.value = dosage;

}
</script>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: wight is already a value (number) so it doesn't have .value parameter
var dosage = weight * 1;
Check console log to debug applications.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing closing tag `/>` in your button

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onClick="calculate()"/>
```

You already stored weight value

```
var weight = document.getElementById('inputweight').value;
```

So you dont need this  `var dosage = weight.value * 1;`

So use var `dosage = weight * 1;`

```
 function calculate() {
    var weight = document.getElementById('inputweight').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var dosage = weight * 1;
    result.value = dosage;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
var weight = document.getElementById('inputweight').value;
```

and this:

```
var dosage = weight.value * 1;
```

do not work together well. You are retrieving the value, then the value of that... which cannot work.
So, replace the second line with:

```
var dosage = weight * 1;
```

Besides: You should check the console for errors, it should show up there.

I assume (or, guess, more correctly) that the ad that is no longer working stops because the javascript execution is typically terminated after an error.

Comment: I managed to get it working thanks to your suggestions :) I think somebody used it to bring down my server though so it will have to go :(

Comment: @JackTorrance i cannot see how one could abuse this little script? But i am glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

Just update this line (remove the `value` attribute which is already extracted above):

```
var dosage = * 1;
```

This will work but you might also want to add this for increased type safety (it parses weight as a number):

```
var dosage = parseInt(weight, 10) * 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code block you are missing a closing `/` at the end of the second input statement. Which should be giving you an issue in your html.

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onClick="calculate()"/>
```

You also don't need weight.value again in the third line of your function. Instead it should be:

```
var dosage = weight * 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle demonstrating your example modified to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/x38ommxs/

```js
function calculate() {
    var weight = document.getElementById('inputweight').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var dosage = weight * 1;
    result.value = dosage;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="inputweight" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onClick="calculate()" />
    <input id="result" />
</div>
```

Added missing closing tag on button

Changed dosage to multiply the value stored in weight by one.